# Enabling support for non WooCommerce themes

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I know that this has been asked before and I am trying to set it up according to the [WooCommerce tutorials](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/) but I don't know what section I am missing in my current non-woocommerce theme.

The home page looks good:http://demo.bergdahl.com/

Other pages have breadcrumbs and look good: http://demo.bergdahl.com/bergdahl-associates-inc/

Even pages like cart, checkout, and my account look good.

Product page looks good (this is partially due to copying the page.php to woocommerce.php and adding the woocommerce call per WC tutorial): http://demo.bergdahl.com/product/6-oz-catridge/

Shop page or Category page looks bad. There are no breadcrumbs and the header is all wrong.

Category page: http://demo.bergdahl.com/product-category/catridges/

Shop page: http://demo.bergdahl.com/shop/

As mentioned above, I did the section of the tutorial where it says to replace the loop (creating a woocommerce.php out of the page.php file and replacing the loop).

Now I am trying to do the section about hooks.

It says to add the code below:

```
//WooCommerce

remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);

remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_start', 10);

add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_end', 10);  

function my_theme_wrapper_start() {

 echo '<section id="main">';

}

function my_theme_wrapper_end() {

  echo '</section>';

}
```

The problem I am having is finding out what my theme wrapper is. The theme I am using is a child theme of the [Builder theme](https://ithemes.com/purchase/builder-theme/). I have looked in the source code and am not seeing anything as easy as `<section id="main">`. I need some help spotting where I can make these changes to make the site work.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Your theme wrapper is probably dynamically generated, so there's probably a function in your theme that you could call, but I am not familiar enough with that theme to advise. I recommend you contact the theme authors and ask them to make the theme WooCommerce compatible.

Comment: I have done that and am waiting to hear back from them. The theme seems a little messy when looking at this area.

Comment: If it were me, I'd probably pick a theme with better WooCommerce support. If you still need a page builder, I'm a fan of Beaver Builder.

Comment: No Builder is the theme. I don't want to pick another theme because this one already exists on the site (which is mid sized) and I don't want to have to do any redesigns. It seems like it should be fairly easy. Hopefully the theme developer will get back to me.

Comment: "It seems like it should be fairly easy" famous last words :)

Comment: Heehee ;) Yeah I know.